# in asp.net login component doesn't redirect

Tags: asp.net, authentication

Dear Experts,
I'm working with visual studio 2010

I’ve  put a login component on my page,  and defined users and roles in the asp.net web application administration

I don’t know why, but it’s not working, it’s not redirecting to the start page

It verifies the right and wrong passwords, and once it’s correct user name and password it doesn’t redirect… it just refresh the page and do nothing

Now, I thought I could debug step by step to know where it goes wrone, but since there is no code written , I don’t know where to put the breakpoint… that is my question

Please can you help me 
.

Comment: you might want to paste in your code...

Answer (score 1):

If the login is succesful, to redirect the user to another page you should use the `DestinationPageUrl` property of the login control.